# How to submit form without reload and pass data back to same page with Node + Express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I've looked at several existing questions on here already. They're all for submitting post requests, but the mechanics should be the same for get requests, so I modified my code to work for get requests. But it's not working correctly.

What's wrong: I submit a form, but the page continues to reload (right now it's redirecting to a new page with the json data.

What I want to do: Submit a form, prevent it from reloading, and display the json data on the same html page

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <form method="GET" action="/search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="term" name="term" placeholder="Find">
        <br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Near">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var $this = $(this);
      $.get($this.attr('action'), function(data) {
        $('pre').text(data);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

And in my express code, I have this:

```
app.get('/search', function(req, res) {
var apiUrl = getApiUrl(req.query);

var apiData = getApiData(apiUrl, function(statusCode, data) {
    // console.log(data);
    // res.render('api-guide', data);
    res.send(data);
  });
});
```

I should note, I'm using handlebars for templating. So the form is in its own template, while the jquery script is in the main template. Would this be why it's not working as expected?

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting an action parameter in your form that is conflicting with your AJAX request. If you remove

```
action="/search"
```

and set the path directly in your AJAX request

```
$.get('/search', function(data) {
    $('pre').text(data);
  });
```

from your form declaration, it should work as you expect.

Comment: But if I remove it from the form, how does it know which route to send the data to?

Comment: I just updated the response, but basically, if you set an action in your form, your browser will 'navigate' to that action at the same time that your ajax request is sent, so you're effectively negating the async call. If you set the path in your ajax call, you should remain in the same page and receive the data that you're requesting.

Comment: No it's still reloading the page even if I remove the action from the form. Maybe it's express that's making the page reload?

Comment: It isn't express because you're receiving the right data when you call the endpoint directly, unless there's a res.render or res.redirect in your getApiData method, it should be fine. Try removing the method from the form as well (since you actually don't need it). And just to make sure it is the form that is failing, trigger the ajax call on its own inside a $(document).ready() declaration